# In Swift, cannot subclass generic: class Foo<T> : T {}

Tags: ios, generics, swift3

I have one class, A, that is sub-classed from `UICollectionViewController`.  Another class, B, is sub-classed from `UIViewController`; B contains a `UICollectionView`.  There is enough common logic between A and B that I would like to factor out the logic into a common extension.  My thinking is that I would create a generic, `Foo<T>`, with the relevant extensions, and then encode A and B as follows:

```
class A : Foo<UICollectionViewController>
```

and

```
class B: Foo<UIViewController>
```

with `Foo<T>` something like this:

```
class Foo<T> : T { ... }
```

This fails because the generic parameter `T` evidently
cannot be referenced as a super-class.

To get around this issue, I tried a solution with protocols and protocol extensions, but that approach did not work:  `@objc` functions (Eg, handlers for `UICollectionViewDataSource`) could not be defined within protocol extensions.

It seems overkill to "normalize" A and B into being the same type of controller.  The common "extensions" I want to add to A and B are handlers for `UICollectionViewDataSource`, `UICollectionViewDelegate`, `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

Is there a way to enable this kind of extended logic with generics?

Answer (score 3):

> There is enough common logic between A and B that I would like to factor out the logic into a common extension

I don't see how the generic is going to help you here; this seems like a misunderstanding of what a generic is.

It appears that your goal is to inject the same implementation of e.g. your UICollectionViewDataSource methods into multiple view controller classes automatically. There is basically *no way* to do that.

Your view controller classes can certainly have a UICollectionViewDataSource method that *calls* common functionality, which you can inject through a protocol extension or whatever; but your classes must still *implement* each UICollectionViewDataSource method *explicitly and individually*.

That's because that's the only way Objective-C is ever going to *see* the implementation and call it in the automatic way that you need for collection view functionality to operate.

Remember, Cocoa is written in Objective-C. It knows nothing of Swift features such as protocol extensions and generics, and can't see them.

Comment: Another way to look at it is: If the thing you want to do here were possible, we'd all be doing it, and Apple would be _telling_ us to do it in WWDC videos. It's an obvious thing to want to do! But we're not doing it, and Apple hasn't discussed it. That's because it's impossible.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was hoping to avoid an extra layer of calls.